# How to read a RAW image file format into OpenCV without any loss of resolution?

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, rawimage

I am trying to import a Nikon '.NEF' file into OpenCV. '.NEF' is the file extension for a RAW file format for pictures captured by Nikon cameras. When I open the file in Preview on a Mac, I see that the resolution is 6000 by 4000, and the picture is extremely clear. However, when I import it into OpenCV, I see only 120 by 160 (by 3 for RGB channels) data points, and this leads to a big loss in resolution.

My understanding is that there are 120 by 160 pixels in the NumPy array storing the information about pixels for OpenCV. I tried using -1 for the IMREAD_UNCHANGED flag, but many pixels were left out and image quality  was greatly affected.

For your reference, here is my code:

```py
# first Jupyter block
img = cv2.imread('DSC_1051.NEF', -1)
img.shape
```

Performing `img.shape` returns (120, 160, 3).

```py
# second Jupyter block
cv2.namedWindow("Resize", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.resizeWindow("Resize", 1000, 700)
  
# Displaying the image
cv2.imshow("Resize", img)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Summary of problem:

- Original image shape is (6000, 4000)
- Open CV imports (120, 160), leading to a big loss in resolution
- Using the IMREAD_UNCHANGED flag did not lead to OpenCV importing **all** the pixels in the image, leading to a loss in quality of the image upon performing `cv2.imshow()`.

My question: how can I use OpenCV to import the desired number of pixels? Is there a specific function that I can use? Am I missing an argument to be passed?

Comment: I didn't even know OpenCV could handle such exotic file formats! does the 160x120 result even resemble what you expect to be in the file? sounds like OpenCV extracts some **thumbnail stored in the file**, which is possible if the thumbnail is a common file format simply embedded. those can often be recovered from arbitrary byte streams.

Comment: Yes, it does resemble what is in the file, but the resolution is really bad.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I see what you mean. I think what you suggested might be the case - OpenCV probably just imports the thumbnail. In fact, the pixel sizes themselves may actually match!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to manipulate RAW images without losing resolution with python you'd need to check on a specialized library like `rawpy`

```
import rawpy

with rawpy.imread('filename.NEF') as raw:
    raw_image = raw.raw_image
```

You can check the [rawpy documentation](https://letmaik.github.io/rawpy/api/) for more information

**Notes:**

- To install rawpy, Python<=3.7 is required
- If you explain a little bit more what do u need to do with the image I could help you with that

**Example 1:** `how to save .NEF as .jpg`

*Option A:* rawpy + Pillow (you need to install `Pillow` too)

```
import rawpy
from PIL import Image

with rawpy.imread('filename.NEF') as raw:
    rgb = raw.postprocess(use_camera_wb=True)
    Image.fromarray(rgb).save('image.jpg', quality=90, optimize=True)
```

*Option B:* rawpy + cv2

```
import rawpy
import cv2

with rawpy.imread('filename.NEF') as raw:
    rgb = raw.postprocess(use_camera_wb=True)
    bgr = cv2.cvtColor(rgb, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
    cv2.imwrite("image.jpg",bgr)
```

**Quality comparison**

I test the code with this [19.2mb .NEF image](https://s3.amazonaws.com/Sample_NEFs/blackbird.nef.zip) and I got these results:

| Method | .jpg output size | Dimensions |
| --- | --- | --- |
| PIL | 9kb | 320x212 |
| cv2 | 14kb | 320x212 |
| **rawpy** + PIL | 1.4mb | 4284 × 2844 |
| **rawpy** + cv2 | 2.5mb | 4284 × 2844 |

**Example 2:** `show .NEF with cv2`

```
import rawpy
import cv2

with rawpy.imread('filename.NEF') as raw:
    rgb = raw.postprocess(use_camera_wb=True)
    bgr = cv2.cvtColor(rgb, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)

    cv2.imshow('image', bgr)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```